# Finding the last ancestor for each record in a self-join association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table Products(id, product_id, (name)...)

Each product is owned by another product (this chain can have multiple links)

The 'name' attribute is only defined on the last ancestor in the product chain, so if I want to display a list of products, i'll have to recursively query for the name of each record.

Because of this, given a list of product ids, I want to return the oldest ancestor for each one of these, so that I may eager load these instead.

Ive have tried using the recursive self join tree in postgres, but have not been able to come up with anything that works

my attempt:

```
self.where('products.id IN
                  (WITH RECURSIVE tree(id) AS (
                     SELECT product.id
                     WHERE product.id IN (?)
                   UNION ALL
                     SELECT product.id
                     JOIN tree ON product.id = tree.id)
                    SELECT id FROM tree)', product_ids)
```

any help is much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Please post some sample data ( as `insert into`) and the expected result (as formatted text). An additional http://sqlfiddle.com would also be nice

Comment: Not being able to give you answer, but this blog article [Using Recursive SQL with ActiveRecord trees](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/recursive-sql-in-activerecord) might help.